# Fold source blocks when hiding their entries?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

**Q:** how do I make source blocks fold automatically when I hide the contents of their entry?

I'd like source code blocks to fold automatically whenever I hide an entry so that they're always out of the way until I specifically want to see them.  Out of the box, however, their visibility seems to be independent of their home entry's visibility.

For example, if I have:

```
* An entry
  #+begin_src R
    x <- 1:10
  #+end_src

Some descriptive text.
```

I can toggle the visibility of the source block with <kbd>TAB</kbd> when point is on the `begin_src` line.  However, when I hide (fold) the *entry* and then show (unfold) it again, the source block seems to remember it's prior visibility state: if it was visible/open, it will be visible when I show/unfold the entry, and if it was invisible/closed, it will be invisible/closed when I show/unfold the entry.

*I want to fold/hide my source blocks automatically whenever I fold/hide the entry that contains them.*  How do I do that?

PS I'm just now learning how to use source blocks, so I may be missing an obvious solution.  Apologies if so.

Answer (score 2):

In emacs 25.1 there is `org-cycle-hook`.
I've stolen `org-cycle-hide-drawers` and adapted it to the case of blocks.
The resulting code below does exactly what you want in emacs 25.1.

```el
(defun org-cycle-hide-blocks (state &optional exceptions)
  "Re-hide all blocks after a visibility state change.
When non-nil, optional argument EXCEPTIONS is a list of strings
specifying which blocks should not be hidden."
  (when (and (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
         (not (memq state '(overview folded contents))))
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((globalp (memq state '(contents all)))
             (beg (if globalp (point-min) (point)))
             (end (if globalp (point-max)
            (if (eq state 'children)
            (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point))
              (org-end-of-subtree t)))))
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward org-block-regexp (max end (point)) t)
      (unless (member-ignore-case (match-string 1) exceptions)
        (let ((block (org-element-at-point)))
          (when (memq (org-element-type block) '(src-block))
        (org-hide-block-toggle t)
        ;; Make sure to skip block entirely or we might flag
        ;; it another time when matching its ending line with
        ;; `org-block-regexp'.
        (goto-char (org-element-property :end block))))))))))

(add-hook 'org-cycle-hook 'org-cycle-hide-blocks)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It kind of works, but has problems with some of the blocks.  For example, it correctly hides blocks with headers such as `#+begin_src R`, but not those such as `#+begin_src R :results silent`.

Comment: @Dan Just tried it with `#+begin_src R :results silent`. Works as expected. Which version of emacs do you have? Could it be that you have some spelling error by accident in the keywords for the source block?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's going on.  I'm on 24.5 right now.

Comment: That's interesting because the doc of `org-cycle-hook` says "This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in version 25.1 of Emacs. Maybe, it is just the changed default value. **Maybe, you should add a complete example (in your question) for the reproduction of the problem.** In my opinion it is okay to post it in the question because it is one case that should work.

Comment: @Dan I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with emacs 24.3. Some features such as `nadvice` do not work with 24.3. So I installed `emacs-snapshot` and this is 25.1. Maybe, this is an interesting option for you, too?